# Jenkins How to zip , remove and transfer directory?

Tags: angular, jenkins, continuous-deployment, jenkins-cli

I am trying to transferring angular 5 build to my server.

My issue is that folder is not deleting over ssh configuration. But files are being transferring.

**Here is my Transfer set config :**

[image] 
**And here is my build success output :** 
[image]

What i am missing or If i am doing wrong configuration. 
Please guide someone.

Thanks.

Comment: Try to add like this  `rm -r /your relative path/dist`

Comment: @ShaikNizamuddin Thanks , its worked.